# Rails: array created in one model, reach in from form in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, select, models

I've got a form view of an Order model (orders_form.html.erb) with a select option:

```
<%= f.select :pay_type, PaymentType.array_of_payment_types,
             :prompt => 'Select a payment method' %>
```

PaymentType is another model and .array_of_payment_types is an array created out of the entries in the payment_type_name column, like so:

```
def self.array_of_payment_types
  @array_of_payment_types ||= PaymentType.pluck(:pay_type_name)
end
```

... from models\payment_type.rb

But I get a proc 'empty?' error:

> undefined method `empty?' for #

I hope my problem is clear, it seems like there is an obvious solution but I haven't found one reading other questions so far...

I will update with the relationships in the models...

My models:

payment_type.rb:

```
class PaymentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pay_type_name

  has_many :orders

  validates :pay_type_name, :uniqueness

  def self.names
    all.collect { |pt| pt.pay_type_name }
  end 

  def self.array_of_payment_types
    PaymentType.all.map{ |p| [p.pay_type_name, p.id] }
  end
end
```

order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :email, :name, :pay_type, :payment_type_id, :cart_id, 
                  :product_id

  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :payment_type

  #PAYMENT_TYPES = ['Check','Purchase order','Credit card']

  validates :name, :address, :email, :presence => true
  validates  :pay_type,
             :presence => true,
             :inclusion => { :in => proc { PaymentType.array_of_payment_types } }

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you positive your method isn't returning nil, and that the array is in the right format for the `select` method?

Comment: I am pretty sure because I fixed that array in another error an hour ago. That array is passed into order.rb for a validates statement, and after a long time figuring it out, it now works. So the array couldn't be returning nil. But I will check in console. Is it possible to check that in the console?

Sorry, I am very very new to RoR, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select):

```
# in the view:
<%= f.select :pay_type, options_for_select(PaymentType.array_of_payment_types),
         :prompt => 'Select a payment method' %>

# in the PaymentType model:
def self.array_of_payment_types
  PaymentType.all.map{ |p| [p.pay_type_name, p.id] }
end
```

You also need to update your validates statement in the Order model:

```
validates  :pay_type,
           :presence => true,
           :inclusion => { :in => proc { PaymentType.pluck(:pay_type_name) } }
```

Comment: That produces a slightly different error, one which I am afraid of because I've seen it 2million times in the past two days :-(

"You need to supply at least one validation"

Comment: Does it come from a Model Validation? Can you post both PaymentType validates and Order validates please?

Comment: Could have something to do with the validations, but I don't know. It still says it comes from line #28 in _form.html.erb in the browser

Comment: and what does this line do/says?

Comment: Sorry, this line is the select line, with the array posted above

Comment: Add true at the end of the validates: `validates :pay_type_name, :uniqueness => true`, then restart the server and try again

Comment: Would you believe that works!?! Fantastic, I can finally move on from this terrible nightmare - cheers buddy ;-)

Comment: W00T W00T ! This missing `true` was the reason of the "You need to supply at least one validation" error ;)